# Swift: Thread 0 Crashed, unsure what to look for in crash log

Tags: swift, crash, breakpoints

I've submitted 4 versions of my app, all of which loaded (for me and reviewers), with the latest version the reviewer is claiming it's crashing upon being loaded. I have only made minor changes and don't know what I could have changed to make it crash. It's running on iOS 8.2 (not sure if the recent iOS update to 8.3 could be any problem). It works on the simulator and on my own iPhone.

This is the crash log, you can see it says it crashes at Thread 0:

```
Incident Identifier: CC33D92C-ED28-4F30-8215-2B17B1F2543D
CrashReporter Key:   96d36abd7f6b404637584810e2eb88be733e9acb
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             My App [2809]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          a.My-App
Version:             1.3 (1.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-04-14 15:25:25.666 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-04-14 15:25:25.396 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000925e8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   My App      0x00000001000925e8 0x100088000 + 42472
1   UIKit                           0x0000000188a94c80 0x188a84000 +     68736
2   UIKit                           0x0000000188a94990 0x188a84000 + 67984
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188a9b1cc 0x188a84000 + 94668
4   UIKit                           0x0000000188a9887c 0x188a84000 + 84092
5   UIKit                           0x0000000188b0a8e8 0x188a84000 + 551144
6   UIKit                           0x0000000188d1ea90 0x188a84000 + 2730640
7   UIKit                           0x0000000188d21204 0x188a84000 + 2740740
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188d1f774 0x188a84000 + 2733940
9   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018c85d3c4 0x18c844000 + 103364
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018400c278 0x183f2c000 + 918136
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018400b380 0x183f2c000 + 914304
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001840095a4 0x183f2c000 + 906660
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f352d0 0x183f2c000 + 37584
14  UIKit                           0x0000000188b00438 0x188a84000 + 508984
15  UIKit                           0x0000000188afafa8 0x188a84000 + 487336
16  My App      0x00000001000e6ae4 0x100088000 + 387812
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195ef6a04 0x195ef4000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195ff4c24 0x195ff4000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ed9e6c 0x195ec8000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ecb998 0x195ec8000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019600fc78 0x195ff4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a92d8 0x1960a8000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a8eec 0x1960a8000 + 3820

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: FBSSerialQueue
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195ff4e48 0x195ff4000 + 3656
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ed7f3c 0x195ec8000 + 65340
2   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018c85d384 0x18c844000 + 103300
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ec9990 0x195ec8000 + 6544
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ec9950 0x195ec8000 + 6480
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ed40a0 0x195ec8000 + 49312
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ecca58 0x195ec8000 + 19032
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ed6314 0x195ec8000 + 58132
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ed7c48 0x195ec8000 + 64584
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a9228 0x1960a8000 + 4648
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a8eec 0x1960a8000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019600fc78 0x195ff4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a92d8 0x1960a8000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a8eec 0x1960a8000 + 3820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019600fc78 0x195ff4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a92d8 0x1960a8000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a8eec 0x1960a8000 + 3820

Thread 6 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195ff4e0c 0x195ff4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195ff4c84 0x195ff4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018400b720 0x183f2c000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184009674 0x183f2c000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183f352d0 0x183f2c000 + 37584
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001829b102c 0x182998000 + 102444
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001829a3a0c 0x182998000 + 47628
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960abdc4 0x1960a8000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960abd20 0x1960a8000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001960a8ef4 0x1960a8000 + 3828

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000196515398   x1: 0x000000018926c502   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000196049a74
    x4: 0x000000016fd75a28   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000200000000000   x9: 0x00000001965153c0  x10: 0x00000001741f4200  x11: 0x000000040000000f
   x12: 0x00000001741f4220  x13: 0x000001a5965153c1  x14: 0x0000000170221478  x15: 0x0000000000000008
   x16: 0x000000018926c502  x17: 0x0000000195891b94  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000014e825200
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000174092980  x22: 0x0000000196515398  x23: 0x0000000170057af0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000199ece0a8
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd76230   lr: 0x0000000100091398
    sp: 0x000000016fd76120   pc: 0x00000001000925e8 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x100088000 - 0x100107fff My App arm64  <dd3a1be3c9ac38209450aed3e8166c75> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/My App
0x100120000 - 0x1002abfff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <5b3c2ad007c73590aabdc2554ff30d4a> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x100408000 - 0x10041ffff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <4df212c0adc635d39677885bf1eb5500> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100440000 - 0x100443fff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <652ee890902b3ea68b86a72cd280faa5> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x100458000 - 0x10045ffff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <6883570852443a6db73321866cb0c1c2> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x10047c000 - 0x10047ffff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <cd8f8e2d57113862afda4788f098adaa> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x1004a4000 - 0x1004effff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <44c6c5841e3b3c9486958cbf1a534bd4> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x100538000 - 0x10053ffff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <252990df94bf3dc899190b1d8df925df> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x100564000 - 0x100567fff libswiftSecurity.dylib arm64  <c6fd1c806cfe38cba2b21c780642b0fb> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftSecurity.dylib
0x100574000 - 0x100577fff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <607f7c198f783fea841ce232f2981202> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9318A062-5BD1-4F3E-A6EC-FD5521B89C53/My App.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x1200ac000 - 0x1200d3fff dyld arm64  <75c68bbe28b13fcd91014f15139742dc> /usr/lib/dyld
0x182800000 - 0x182994fff AVFoundation arm64  <c69cb19d6db0339bbfb4c18fa7f4f26c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x182998000 - 0x1829fcfff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <fdd31b28c0ec3f76b8f0fa9a057e43d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x182a40000 - 0x182a40fff Accelerate arm64  <a2161063fee1315193bc488d0354f43e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x182a58000 - 0x182c77fff vImage arm64  <74eb7b77dbcd321db86e784be9353a08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x182c78000 - 0x182d1ffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <56e8b79c2c03379dad45fe2ea1a4052f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x182d20000 - 0x18309afff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <fd491ae19b12315babb621650a0eef76> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x18309c000 - 0x1830b1fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <9307063a5e1833abbb857a9ec4c5369e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1830b4000 - 0x18311cfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <d4d2b4a941213e2b81f3ddafd6b8a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x183120000 - 0x183143fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <92a0dd635be43dfe8c128c888ef37c0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x183144000 - 0x183144fff vecLib arm64  <9248f57f1d8430219a810aa93254f157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x183148000 - 0x183177fff Accounts arm64  <4199851056d4376aa4d8668b83c85454> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x183518000 - 0x1837d8fff AudioToolbox arm64  <760c2dc59fa13660a769cc1b052d41e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x183978000 - 0x183b8bfff CFNetwork arm64  <df5535d1633f375aa889f755db0a93b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x183c2c000 - 0x183c91fff CoreAudio arm64  <b85ca2cdb29639ccb5f6405baf597027> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x183cdc000 - 0x183f28fff CoreData arm64  <af13d4e830e13607b745fe57f90e5d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x183f2c000 - 0x18428afff CoreFoundation arm64  <6548b13bef1f3f958d96266f7c4c44e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18428c000 - 0x1843eefff CoreGraphics arm64  <92162d42d08d357ab66302a38d724828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x184444000 - 0x184446fff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <8f40b7d9b97b344f9c7a5a0b79bdc2b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x184448000 - 0x184453fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <a40d7bdbbe6c3317bcf4c20c085df848> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x184648000 - 0x184666fff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <975284709e51353690ec8a651b43c1db> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x184668000 - 0x18479afff CoreImage arm64  <d7a2122dc8173803bc220fde3cfebfdf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x184834000 - 0x1848f7fff CoreMedia arm64  <403a9798401c3b70a207e0e236454c0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1848f8000 - 0x1849e6fff CoreMotion arm64  <61338e072f2a385ab4e315975f23eea2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x1849e8000 - 0x184a59fff CoreTelephony arm64  <450440ee68593b8e9c951cdf838264f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x184a5c000 - 0x184b64fff CoreText arm64  <4a9633cee0393585a98fcf07410e0828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x184b68000 - 0x184b85fff CoreVideo arm64  <217e5b69f6d03f8893f01de3e40915a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x184e60000 - 0x1850b8fff Foundation arm64  <509b484fb7b634b19673d50296d8278f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x185200000 - 0x18526bfff IOKit arm64  <311bed1f2b893195b8c0564d8925bfa2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x18526c000 - 0x18550ffff ImageIO arm64  <7d3c81746f2c3f1488b3efc633d21633> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x185510000 - 0x1859b1fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <1ad0ed311f3e3897bac70f3388fc05be> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1862ec000 - 0x1862f2fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <4e3e82a2b09a38fcbf01843f97d5e604> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x186518000 - 0x186936fff MediaToolbox arm64  <c2103a7dd16e3f67abfe898b039061e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x186a10000 - 0x186a88fff Metal arm64  <eb54636e26cd3dee870fa5e4fb708fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x186a8c000 - 0x186b3dfff MobileCoreServices arm64  <daa61b358c17365792c20df791224e26> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x187db8000 - 0x187dc2fff OpenGLES arm64  <8824bb82d43937a9b0aa3870ece35772> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x187dc8000 - 0x187dc9fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <34760639fb2331dcaa229ba0e418c1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x187dcc000 - 0x187dcffff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <e6f967504d5937d59223598de12969ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x187dd0000 - 0x187dd4fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <30969b8fde9f36c4a6a0293c03e74e5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x187dd8000 - 0x187de2fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <5942ea8060c63e86b3ffbfb76b061276> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x187de4000 - 0x187e2ffff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <3e46a6b44be93e5689e4851c76b2db04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1883cc000 - 0x18855efff QuartzCore arm64  <e47923f08f343c3e98e77f22f674f234> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1887e4000 - 0x188838fff Security arm64  <80b60ba1feba39afb6686e342398cce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
```

... and so on. Is there something related to UIKit, FrontBoardServices, or CoreFoundation that's causing it to crash?

Comment: Well the top frame of the crashing thread is in "My App" so can you give some context?  What is the code at the crash point?  Also, the crash report is incomplete.  There were more images that should be listed after that last line.  Please provide the full crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

It's not a crash. You have set a breakpoint.

Comment: I don't think so. SIGTRAP is not caused by a breakpoint. Also OP claims that it happened during review of a submitted app.

Comment: Yep, I haven't set breakpoints. The crash log I posted is what the apple reviewer gave me (as I said it's never crashed on launch for me).